# how to transfer an array to two-d array in java

Tags: java, list

i want to transfer an n elements array to a two-d array in java.

For example:

[1,2,3,4]

this array should be transferred to an two-d array

[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4] [3,4]]

- the first line of the two-d array is 1, 2.
- the second line of the two- array is 1, 3.
- the third line of the two-array is 1, 4.
- the forth line of the two-array is 2, 3.
- the fifth line of the two-array is 2, 4.
- the last line is 3, 4

Comment: What have your tried?? And should the number of columns always be 2??

Comment: @RohitJain i have no idea about that

Comment: @Justin.. Then how would you divide it when there are 10 elements in your array?? Please be clear with your specs..

Comment: So, you are trying to create a two-dimensional array of all combinations of the elements in the first array? Specific details are necessary.

Comment: if there is a 6 element array. [1,2,3,4,5,6]
the first line of the two-d array should be 1, 2
the second..................................1, 3
the third ..................................1, 4
the fifth...................................1, 5
the sixth...................................1, 6
the seventh.................................2, 3
the eight ..................................2, 4
so on so far

Comment: @Justin.. Well now that it is clear what you want.. It doesn't seem to be that tough. You should give it a try.. Write some `Algorithm` on Paper. and then see how it works..

Comment: It sounds like you just want all the possible pairs that can be made from the elements of the original array. If that's what you want, you should edit your question. You should also select the answer by @TarunGupta if it helps you solve your problem (which it kinda should).

Answer (score 8):

Without writing any code for you...

Think about how big your 2d array needs to be.
Recognize that you'll need to loop over the contents of your source array to get each value into your destination array.

**So it will look something like...**

Create a 2d array of appropriate size.
Use a for loop to loop over your 1d array.
Inside that for loop, you'll need to figure out where each value in the 1d array should go in the 2d array. Try using the mod function against your counter variable to "wrap around" the indices of the 2d array.
I'm being intentionally vague, seeing as this is homework. Try posting some code so we can see where you get stuck.

Or you can use that code:-

```
int array2d[][] = new int[10][3];


for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
       array2d[i][j] = array1d[(j*10) + i];
```

Comment: array2d[i][j] = array1d[(i*3) + j];

Answer (score 2):

From Permutation and combination you can get the row length of the 2D array (ie. n!/r!*(n-r)!).

- `getLengthOfArray` method does this.
- `calculatePermutation` is a helper method to calculate permutaion.
- `transferToTwoDArray` will give you the right answer.

```
public int[][] transferToTwoDArray(final int[] oneDArray)
{
    assert null != oneDArray;
    final int length = oneDArray.length;
    assert length > 2;

    final int newArrayLength = getLengthOfArray(length, 2);
    final int[][] newArray = new int[newArrayLength][2];

    int nextRowIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int nextValue = i + 1;

        while (nextValue < length)
        {
            newArray[nextRowIndex][0] = oneDArray[i];
            newArray[nextRowIndex][1] = oneDArray[nextValue++];
            nextRowIndex++;
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

/**
 * Calculate permutation.
 * 
 * @param length
 *            the length
 * @return the int
 */
private int calculatePermutation(final int length)
{
    if (length == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return length * calculatePermutation(length - 1);
}

/**
 * Gets the length of array.
 * 
 * @param length
 *            the length
 * @param arrayDimention
 *            the array dimention
 * @return the length of array
 */
private int getLengthOfArray(final int length, final int arrayDimention)
{
    return calculatePermutation(length)
            / ((calculatePermutation(arrayDimention)) * (calculatePermutation(length - arrayDimention)));
}
```

Cheers,
Chand.